# What does $this->load->model('foo_model'); actually do In codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Does the controller extends the foo_model or just we are loading the whole model itself?

If it is loading how can i create a proper object for model(foo_model) class..

coz i used something like `$obj = new foo_model();`

my model class looks like this:

```
class foo_model extends CI_model{
public $model_variable;

function foo_model(){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->$model_variable = $this->db->query('mysql query returning array of values')->result();

}
```

}

And my controller is like this

```
class foo1_controller extends CI_controller{

public function foo1_controller()
{
    //loading basic libraries and helper fn.
}

public function some_controllerfn()
{
    $this->load->model('foo_model');
    $foo_details = new foo_model();
    //print $foo_details as objects
}
```

}

the problems i face here is 
the model is called twice when i use the controller function 
and i also want $foo_details to be returned as objects.
what will be the proper way to do this ,any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you gone through the documentation? I'm pretty sure it must have some explanation about it.

Comment: Not only that, it's open source. Hell it's PHP it reads like a book.

Comment: You can access the `foo_model` object from the controller as `$this->foo_model` after loading it.

Answer (score 0):

The `model` method of `Loader` will instantiate the model object for the passed model name.

It will recursively call the function if an `array` of model names are passed. It will load the model file from the allowed list of paths, then instantiate the model object and assign it to a member variable of the same name in the controller.

Comment: so what to do if we want to wrap all the variables in model in object in controller and how represent it.